# How can I use one spyOn for diferrent case in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, react-testing-library

Here is the problem. I want to add different classes to component if I get different orders from urlsSearchParams. But the value is always the same and the desc test never works. here is the code:

```
describe("<CandidatesTableHeader/>", function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest
            .spyOn(useSearchParams, "useSearchParams")
            .mockReturnValueOnce([{
                get: (name: string): string => 'asc',
            }] as any)
            .mockReturnValueOnce([{
                get: (name: string): string => 'desc',
            }] as any);
    });

    it("Candidates table header should have asc class if it exists in urlParams", async () => {
        customRender(<CandidatesTableHeader columns={mockedColumns}/>);

        const tableHeader = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderSortable);
        const orderBlock = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderOrder);

        fireEvent.click(tableHeader);
        expect(orderBlock).toHaveClass('asc');

    });

    it("Candidates table header should have desc class if it exists in urlParams", async () => {
        customRender(<CandidatesTableHeader columns={mockedColumns}/>)

        const tableHeader = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderSortable);
        const orderBlock = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderOrder);

        fireEvent.click(tableHeader);
        expect(orderBlock).toHaveClass('desc');
    });
});
```

and the desc is never works because 'asc' is always in the value.

what is get in console

```
  ● <CandidatesTableHeader/> › Candidates table header should have desc class if it exists in urlParams

    expect(element).toHaveClass("desc")

    Expected the element to have class:
      desc
    Received:
      sortIcon asc

      79 |
      80 |         fireEvent.click(tableHeader);
    > 81 |         expect(orderBlock).toHaveClass('desc');
         |                            ^
      82 |     });
      83 | });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `beforeEach` will be executed before running each test case and in each test case, the first call will consume the value from the first `mockReturnValueOnce(...)`.

You can solve it by using `beforeAll` instead of `beforeEach`,

```js
describe("<CandidatesTableHeader/>", function () {
    beforeAll(() => {
        jest
            .spyOn(useSearchParams, "useSearchParams")
            .mockReturnValueOnce([{
                get: (name: string): string => 'asc',
            }] as any)
            .mockReturnValueOnce([{
                get: (name: string): string => 'desc',
            }] as any);
    });

    it("Candidates table header should have asc class if it exists in urlParams", async () => {
        customRender(<CandidatesTableHeader columns={mockedColumns}/>);

        const tableHeader = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderSortable);
        const orderBlock = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderOrder);

        fireEvent.click(tableHeader);
        expect(orderBlock).toHaveClass('asc');

    });

    it("Candidates table header should have desc class if it exists in urlParams", async () => {
        customRender(<CandidatesTableHeader columns={mockedColumns}/>)

        const tableHeader = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderSortable);
        const orderBlock = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderOrder);

        fireEvent.click(tableHeader);
        expect(orderBlock).toHaveClass('desc');
    });
});
```

---

**OR**

**I recommend** you to move the `spy` inside the test cases as below.

```js
describe("<CandidatesTableHeader/>", function () {

    it("Candidates table header should have asc class if it exists in urlParams", async () => {
    
        jest
            .spyOn(useSearchParams, "useSearchParams")
            .mockReturnValueOnce([{
                get: (name: string): string => 'asc',
            }] as any);
    
        customRender(<CandidatesTableHeader columns={mockedColumns}/>);

        const tableHeader = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderSortable);
        const orderBlock = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderOrder);

        fireEvent.click(tableHeader);
        expect(orderBlock).toHaveClass('asc');

    });

    it("Candidates table header should have desc class if it exists in urlParams", async () => {
    
        jest
            .spyOn(useSearchParams, "useSearchParams")
            .mockReturnValueOnce([{
                get: (name: string): string => 'desc',
            }] as any);
            
        customRender(<CandidatesTableHeader columns={mockedColumns}/>)

        const tableHeader = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderSortable);
        const orderBlock = await screen.findByTestId(TestIds.CandidatesTableHeaderOrder);

        fireEvent.click(tableHeader);
        expect(orderBlock).toHaveClass('desc');
    });
});
```